# In which class implements JpaRepository interface in spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to know where implement JpaRepository interface

```
JpaRepository extends  from PagingAndSortingRepository interface

PagingAndSortingRepository extends  from CrudRepository interface

PagingAndSortingRepository extends  from Repository interface
```

but where is implementation of these interface?

how all the method in those interface work( like findAll, findById, deleteAll etc)?

Comment: You don't. It works just like that.

Answer (score 0):

These interfaces are part of the `Spring-Data-JPA` Project.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/

For e.g. JpaRepository has an implementation SimpleJpaRepository, you can find the implementation here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java

Gitter link: https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-data

Answer (score -1):

The "implementation" is build on runtime. So basicly you create interface and thats it, it is ready to `@Autowire`.